# If $S^{-1}$ exists, can we prove at least one of its block matrices can be inverted

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

As title

If $S_{k\times k}$ is a nonsingular matrix , does (m,n,p,q) exist certainly such that S =$\pmatrix{A_{m\times p}&B_{n\times p}\\C_{m\times q}&D_{n\times q}}$ where at least one of its block matrices(A, B, C, or D) is nonsingular?

Is  the statement true?

Or, is it possible that all block matrices of S can't be inverted  $\forall$ (m,n,p,q), but S is nonsingular?

Update:

Hence, if S is a k-by-k matrix, then $S_{11}=S_{1k}=S_{k1}=S_{kk}=0$.

Since if $S_{11}\neq 0$, then let A= $S_{11}$ which can be inverted, similarly to $S_{1k}$, $S_{k1}$ and $S_{kk}$.

Comment: The words *singular* and *nonsingular* apply only to square matrices. You also seem to have your directions mixed up: An $m\times p$ matrix has $m$ rows and $p$ columns. But you need $A$ to be $m\times m$, $D$ to be $n\times n$, etc.

Comment: @TedShifrin if A is nonsingular, then m=p. Similarly, if D is nonsingular, then n=q.
However, if only B is nonsingular, then n=p, but m may not equal p.

Comment: Same goes for singular.

Comment: @TedShifrin I only need at least one block matrix which is square and nonsingular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the update to the question. But daw's example can be tweaked so that it is still not possible to divide in square blocks with at least one invertible:
$$
\left( \begin{array}{cc|cc}
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{array}\right).
$$
The only way to subdivide this is as four $2\times2$ blocks, in which case all are singular; or as $1\times1$ and $3\times3$ (where I guess the OP wants to say that non-square matrices are singular). As the four corners are singular, no such division is possible.

Comment: You really helped me a lot !!!!!!!!!!!!
Actually I want to invert S by $A^{-1}$, $B^{-1}$, $C^{-1}$ or $D^{-1}$， but I can't make sure that at least one of them exists.

Answer (score 3):

No. Take this matrix consisting of four $2\times2$ submatrices:
$$
\left( \begin{array}{cc|cc}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \end{array}\right).
$$
It is a permutation matrix, hence invertible.

Comment: Let A=$\pmatrix{1}$, then $A^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: Hence, if S is a k-by-k matrix, then $S_{11}=S_{1k}=S_{k1}=S_{kk}=0$

Comment: But your question didn't specify that you could choose the sizes of the blocks. They were presumed given.